# Bash No such file or Directory Error (Cache Simulator)

Tags: c, linux, bash, compiler-errors, terminal

I am design a cache simulator for to count miss,hits,eviction.I tried to compile my program with the following command ,it worked perfectly without any error,

```
Program
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <getopt.h>
#include <strings.h>
#include <limits.h>

//#include "cachelab.h"

/* Always use a 64-bit variable to hold memory addresses*/
typedef unsigned long long int mem_addr_t;

 /* a struct that groups cache parameters together */
typedef struct
{
int s;                       /* 2**s cache sets */
int b;                       /* cacheline block size 2**b bytes */
int E;                       /* number of cachelines per set */
int S;                       /* number of sets, derived from S = 2**s */
int B;                       /* cacheline block size (bytes), derived from B = 2**b */
} cache_param_t;

int verbosity;

/* printUsage - Print usage info */
void printUsage( char *argv[] )
{
printf( "Usage: %s [-hv] -s <num> -E <num> -b <num> -t <file>\n", argv[0] );
printf( "Options:\n" );
printf( "  -h         Print this help message.\n" );
printf( "  -v         Optional verbose flag.\n" );
printf( "  -s <num>   Number of set index bits.\n" );
printf( "  -E <num>   Number of lines per set.\n" );
printf( "  -b <num>   Number of block offset bits.\n" );
printf( "  -t <file>  Trace file.\n" );
printf( "\nExamples:\n" );
printf( "  %s -s 4 -E 1 -b 4 -t traces/yi.trace\n", argv[0] );
printf( "  %s -v -s 8 -E 2 -b 4 -t traces/yi.trace\n", argv[0] );
exit( 0 );
}

void printSummary( int hit_count, int miss_count, int eviction_count )
{
printf( "hits: %d   misses: %d   evictions: %d\n", hit_count, miss_count, eviction_count );
} 

int main( int argc, char **argv )
{
cache_param_t par;

bzero( &par, sizeof ( par ) );

char *trace_file;
char c;

while ( ( c = getopt( argc, argv, "s:E:b:t:vh" ) ) != -1 )
{
  switch ( c )
  {
     case 's':
        par.s = atoi( optarg );
        break;
     case 'E':
        par.E = atoi( optarg );
        break;
     case 'b':
        par.b = atoi( optarg );
        break;
     case 't':
        trace_file = optarg;
        break;
     case 'v':
        verbosity = 1;
        break;
     case 'h':
        printUsage( argv );
        exit( 0 );
     default:
        printUsage( argv );
        exit( 1 );
  }
}

if ( par.s == 0 || par.E == 0 || par.b == 0 || trace_file == NULL )
{
  printf( "%s: Missing required command line argument\n", argv[0] );
  printUsage( argv );
  exit( 1 );
}

/* TODO: Compute S and B based on information passed in */

//Compute S and B, 2^s and 2^b respectively
par.S = ( 1 << par.s );
par.B = ( 1 << par.b );

/* TODO: Initialize a cache */

//Structure for a line
typedef struct
{
  int valid;
  mem_addr_t tag;
  int timestamp;
} line_st;

//Structure for a set; a pointer to an array of lines
typedef struct
{
  line_st *lines;
} cache_set;

//Structure for a cache; a pointer to an array of sets
typedef struct
{
  cache_set *sets;
} cache_t;

//allocate space for sets and for lines
cache_t cache;
int i;

cache.sets = malloc( par.S * sizeof ( cache_set ) );
for (i = 0; i < par.S; i++ )
{
  cache.sets[i].lines = malloc( sizeof ( line_st ) * par.E );
}

//counters
int hit_count = 0;
int miss_count = 0;
int eviction_count = 0;

/* TODO: Run the trace simulation */

char act;                    //L,S,M
int size;                    //size read in from file
int TSTAMP = 0;              //value for LRU
int empty = -1;              //index of empty space
int H = 0;                   //is there a hit
int E = 0;                   //is there an eviction
int e;
mem_addr_t addr;

//open the file and read it in
FILE *traceFile = fopen( trace_file, "r" );

if ( traceFile != NULL )
{
  while ( fscanf( traceFile, " %c %llx,%d", &act, &addr, &size ) == 3 )
  {
     int toEvict = 0;             //keeps track of what to evict
     if ( act != 'I' )
     {
        //calculate address tag and set index
        mem_addr_t addr_tag = addr >> ( par.s + par.b );
        int tag_size = ( 64 - ( par.s + par.b ) );
        unsigned long long temp = addr << ( tag_size );
        unsigned long long setid = temp >> ( tag_size + par.b );
        cache_set set = cache.sets[setid];
        int low = INT_MAX; // CHANGED, also added #include <limits.h>

        for (e = 0; e < par.E; e++ ) {
           if ( set.lines[e].valid == 1 ) {
              // CHANGED ORDER: look for hit before eviction candidates
              if ( set.lines[e].tag == addr_tag ) {
                 hit_count++;
                 H = 1;
                 set.lines[e].timestamp = TSTAMP;
                 TSTAMP++;
              }
              // CHANGED WHOLE ELSE: look for oldest for eviction.
              else if ( set.lines[e].timestamp < low ) {
                 low = set.lines[e].timestamp;
                 toEvict = e;
              }
           }
           // CHANGED: if we haven't yet found an empty, mark one that we found.
           else if( empty == -1 ) {
              empty = e;
           }
        }

        //if we have a miss
        if ( H != 1 )
        {
           miss_count++;
           //if we have an empty line
           if ( empty > -1 )
           {
              set.lines[empty].valid = 1;
              set.lines[empty].tag = addr_tag;
              set.lines[empty].timestamp = TSTAMP;
              TSTAMP++; 
           }
           //if the set is full we need to evict
           else if ( empty < 0 )
           {
              E = 1;
              set.lines[toEvict].tag = addr_tag;
              set.lines[toEvict].timestamp = TSTAMP;
              TSTAMP++; // CHANGED: increment TSTAMP here too
              eviction_count++;
           }
        }
        //if the instruction is M, we will always get a hit
        if ( act == 'M' )
        {
           hit_count++;
        }
        //if the -v flag is set print out all debug information
        if ( verbosity == 1 )
        {
           printf( "%c ", act );
           printf( "%llx,%d", addr, size );
           if ( H == 1 )
           {
              printf( "Hit " );
           }
           else if ( H != 1 )
           {
              printf( "Miss " );
           }
           if ( E == 1 )
           {
              printf( "Eviction " );
           }
           // CHANGED: don't print Hit again since 'M' is always going to print Hit above.
           printf( "\n" );
        }
        empty = -1;
        H = 0;
        E = 0;
     }
  }
}

   /* TODO: Clean up cache resources */

/* TODO: Print out real results */
printSummary( hit_count, miss_count, eviction_count );
void printSummary(int hits, int misses, int evictions)
{
 printf("hits:%d misses:%d evictions:%d\n", hits, misses, evictions);
FILE* output_fp = fopen(".csim_results", "w");
fprintf(output_fp, "%d %d %d\n", hits, misses, evictions);
fclose(output_fp);
}
return 0;
}


Compile command
gcc -Wall hello.c -o hello.out -lm

But when i tried to execute the code i am getting the following error :

error while running the program
bash: ./hello:No such file or directory 

The command which i used to run is as follows 

Run command
./hello [hv] -s 5 -E 1 -b 5 -t traces/trans.trace

Expected output
Hits 231 Misses 7 Evictions 0
```

I am pretty sure that the path which i have set while executing the program is correct but i am not able to find the solution to encounter this ? Help me out !!

Answer (score 1):

You compiled with `gcc -Wall hello.c -o hello.out -lm`, so you're looking to execute `./hello.out`.

If you want to run with `./hello`, compile with the line:

```
gcc -Wall hello.c -o hello -lm
```

Comment: I did the way you said for compiling by not including out (hello.out) ,it compiles and runs but this time no output is shown on the terminal

Comment: I don't know what is supposed to appear on the terminal, that would depend on your code. But it would be best to create another question, putting in your code, run command, expected output and perceived output.

Comment: Hi i edited the above question with code ,expected output and with some description ...is it possible to help me out